# OpenMP loops parallelization

Tags: c, linux, parallel-processing, openmp, parallel.for

I am trying to parallelize both loops of this fragment of code:

```
for ( j = 0 ; j < nt2 ; j++ ) {
   dm = MAX_LON + 1;

   for ( i = 0 ; i < nt1 ; i++ ) {
      d = distancia(tabla1[i],tabla2[j]);     
      if ( d < dm ) {
         dm = d;
         im = i;
      }
   }
   ps[j] = im;
}
```

Parallelizing of outer loop succeed:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,d,dm,im)
```

But I still have a problem with the inner one. I tried with e.g. private(d,m) and reduction(max:im), but it doesn't work with any combination. The closest to sequencial results I've got with private(d). Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: You can't nest parallel blocks.

Comment: There are a lot of questions and answers here on SO on the topic of *OpenMP nested loops*.  Do a little more research, you may conclude that parallelisation of just the outer loop is the right way to go.

Comment: I know that I can't nest blocks, but I want to do two options where 
- one: paralalize only outer loop
- two: paralalize only inner loop.
And I have problem with the second one

Comment: You will need to implement a reduction scheme to parallelize the inner loop. See for instance [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53410585/openmp-c-program-run-slower-than-sequential-code/53412396#53412396). As mentioned, there are *many* questions on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Parallelizing the inner loop should be enough to consume all available threads. If you parallelize both it would only generate overhead.